# Customize twitter bootstrap dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I try to use the twitter boostrap dropdown plugin to make an editable dropdown.
For now I have this: http://jsfiddle.net/U9L2J/3/

What I want to do is put a pencil icon and a delete icon at the right of each element of the list (with `<i class="icon-pencil"></i>` and `<i class="icon-remove"></i>`). And trigger an event when these icons are clicked.
So when these icons are clicked, it shouldn't check the checkbox of the element.
All the things I've tried just destroyed completely the CSS of the list...

Any ideas?

Comment: This does not make sense in relation to your example: "So when these icons are clicked, it shouldn't check the checkbox of the element."

Comment: I've updated the jsfiddle, is it better now ? Is the problem more clear ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For those to handle a click event, you should map them up using .on():

```
    $(".icon-remove").on("click", function(e){
    alert('clicked');
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

[Your Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TNCodeMonkey/U9L2J/4/)

**EDIT:
Code Correction:**

```
    $("#layers-dropdown >.layers").on("click","li a label i.icon-remove", function(e){
        alert('clicked');
    e.preventDefault();
});​
```

[Updated Fiddle with dynamic functionality](http://jsfiddle.net/TNCodeMonkey/U9L2J/6/)

Comment: If I add a new layer dynamically, the function isn't bind with the new icon, do I need to bind it manually each time an element is added ? I thought "on" did it automatically...

Comment: No, it will be bound automatically; via .on()

Comment: @Antoine ahhh, I see what you're saying.  I'm looking into it now.

Comment: @Antoine I've fixed the problem, I wasn't creating the .on binding to a concrete element. This is what you need.

Comment: Thanks ! that's interesting, I've never used this second parameter of "on" before.

Comment: @Antoine When loading dynamic content that needs to respond to UI events, it is the way to go.  Sure, you could attach elements, bind that element to an event, and move on.  But you must do this for every added item, and that can get annoying and tedious.  The .on() handler allows you to neatly package all your respective element bindings into one call.  Also, to cancel the binding is '$(element).off('click', functionName);  I am familiar with what you are doing, and this, in my opinion, is the best practice for your needs. If you agree, won't you make this your selected answer? :)

Answer (score 0):

Use preventDefault to stop the checkbox from being checked.

```
​$("i")​​.click(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  // some code here - do your thing!
}​);​
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/PcjNz/

Of course, you should probably bind different click-events to the different icons. This example only prevents the checkbox from being checked...

Comment: This does not take care of the dynamic content bindings.  The .click() event is only going to bind the elements currently on the page.  What you are looking for here is .on/live/etc that will bind to dynamically added elements in the future.

Comment: Actually my main problem here wasn't the dynamic binding, but preventing the checkbox of being checked

Comment: @Antoine and therein lies the issue:  the checkbox will still be checked when you add elements later, because this type of binding does not work with dynamic content.